# How can i avoid Jquery translate `?` to `%3F`

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the follwoing Jquery code to open page on button click passing a parameter but `?` is translated to `%3F` is there anyways to fix this?

```
$("#PrintDocument").click(function () {

    var grid = $("#Billings").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = $("input:checked", grid.tbody).closest("tr");
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    window.location.pathname = '/invoice/billing/Print' + '?productId=' + item.ProductID + '&' + 'runId=' + item.RunID;
   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the pathname which does not have a query string.

```
window.location.href = '/invoice/billing/Print' + '?productId=' + item.ProductID + '&' + 'runId=' + item.RunID;
```